# How to check if there is the same data in the database or not?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I want to check if the newly entered data already exists in the database or not, I searched it and tried many times but it doesn't work the database accept data which already exist in it, I'm using PDO with PHP.

**The database has 1 table called data and this table has 2 columns name and phone**

Here is the code:

```
$connect = new PDO("mysql:host ={$host}; dbname={$database}" , $username , $password);
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE name= :sname AND phone = :sphone");
$statement->execute(array("sname" => $name , "sphone" => $phone));
$count = $statement->rowCount();

if($count > 0){
}else{                      
    $q = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO data(name,phone) VALUES(:aname, :aphone)");
    $q->execute(array("aname" => $name,"aphone" => $phone));
}
```

Comment: Why not use instead unique index `on data (name, phone)` which prevents insertion of duplicate rows ?

Comment: Won't that cause SQL errors ?

Comment: Yes, will, but you can easily handle that error

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure this information should only be inserted once: make the combination of "name" and "phone" unique. This is not exactly what you are asking for, but the result will be the same: no duplicate content.

`ALTER TABLE data   ADD UNIQUE INDEX Index1 (name, phone);`

You now can insert what ever you want: if it is a duplicate the insert action will fail. If needed, you can check on this (specific) failure and notify the user.

Comment: I edited the question and added : The database has 1 table called data and this table has 2 columns name and phone

Comment: @Danny my answer remains the same for 2 or more columns

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$count = $statement->fetchColumn();
```

instead of

```
$count = $statement->rowCount();
```